# How to find voltage drawn across x-y in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

This was a problem given in my basic electrical engineering class. I'm having my final exam in 2 days, can someone please explain to me how this solution was obtained. I'm attaching the solution that a friend of mine got.
[image]

Comment: One of the loops is floating, where is the reference? Actually, both of them are fishy. Is that the *whole* circuit, or is there something else missing?

Comment: That is exactly how I would solve it. You need to watch the polarities carefully. As current flows through a resistor the voltage drops + to -. Which line don't you understand?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen There is X anx Y and voltage between them needs to be calculated. You don't need anything else to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of your friend is correct, basic KVL you need to follow and that is basically how you solve it. However, I was curious about the circuit diagram as it looks incomplete without a reference ground node, so I just simulated it in LTSPice to check the results.

The ground node can be placed at either 5V battery or 10V battery but not to both. As you can see from the spice error log results, the answer 1.52V is correct.

[image][image]

If you ground the -ve terminal of both the batteries, you get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Why would it need a reference node to be complete? If you take a bunch of 9V batteries, they all have 9V between the terminals, even of you don't reference to anything. If you take one battery out of plastic wrapping, it might have few kilovolts of static charge compared to battery next to it and that's fine.

Comment: Because you are taking the difference of two voltages the location of "ground" is immaterial. However, if you place "ground" at two locations in the circuit you are connecting those two places with a wire and possibly changing the circuit topology.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the solution is more obvious if you redraw the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy0mwF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can decompose the circuit in to 3 basic sections as your friend did in his head.
Solve for the voltage across R2 for the upper section and solve for the voltage across R3 in the bottom section which are simple voltage divider problems.

It's now a matter of summing up the various voltages, i.e.,
$$ V(X,Y) = V(B,Y) + V(A,B) + V(X,A) $$
Mind the polarity of the voltages when you sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

If the diagram was redrawn with an added resistor, you would probably know how to solve it. You would write 3 KVL mesh equations and solve it (3 equations, 3 unknowns).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWbcdH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, the instructor made it harder for you by making it simpler! They were trying to separate those who solve problems like robots and those who can think through a problem.

As the new resistor (R5) approaches infinity, you have the original problem.

[image]